# Error when spaces are removed in string when converted from tuple

Tags: python, tuples

```
word="testing"
tup_1=tuple(word)
word2=str(tup_1)
assert "('t','e','s','t','i','n','g')" == word2
```

It is looking correct only but giving assertion error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFYZc.png)

Why is it giving error? Can anyone explain?

Comment: What do you intend to get? do you want to see the combination of given list is equal to word2? then assert is not the command you need. if it is the case let me know to write a simple code for it

Comment: The error is `AssertionError` so you aren't missing much if you don't click on the link.

Comment: I want to know how can we remove those spaces which python gives default(if any)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its giving error as the strings are not equal. There are spaces in between:

```
>>> assert "('t','e','s','t','i','n','g')" == word2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> assert "('t', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g')" == word2
>>>
```

Comment: @poharsrikar Generally when Python prints lists or tuples, it puts spaces between the values. [1,2,3] will be printed as this [1, 2, 3]. So if you do str(list or tuple), it will include the spaces

Comment: Thank you.Is there any way to remove spaces(if any)?

Comment: Is there any way to remove those spaces?(if any)

Comment: Not directly, as far as I'm aware. When you call str(tuple), it calls the `__str__`method. If you do want it in the format without spaces do this `'('+','.join(map(str,tup_1))+')'`